# SQL Server : how find difference inside one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this structure

```
| datetime | name | port | value1 | value2 |
```

and every 10 minutes I run a script that imports a large number of values into this table.

I would like to have a query that will use 2 given datetime values and return those rows (with name and port) where `value1` or `value2` has changed between those two date/times more than some value.

I tried to use intersect but did not succeed.

Comment: can u give some examples

Comment: can you show some example data?

Comment: Have tried below in where clause:
datetime < 'start time' and datetime > 'endtme'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`.  Here is an example:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.datetime = @DATETIME1 and t2.datetime = @DATETIME2 and
        t1.name = t2.name and
        t1.port = t2.port
where abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1) > @THRESHHOLD or
      abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2) > @THRESHHOLD;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Didn't know that I can join my table to itself. Sorry cannot vote because of low rep here.